# display product failed

Tags: magento-1.9, products, frontend

I inserted a product into the catalog from Magento admin panel with correct attributes (visibility, status, etc..). I checked into Magento db and the product exists.
The theme installed is the default theme and, at frontend, there isn't some products display and I don't see the inserted product. I try to search the product into entire store but the research don't produce some results.
Can you help me, please?
Thanks.

Comment: can you check with `site-url/product-url.html`

Comment: do reindex it will solve your prolem and also check product is in stock or not

Comment: @Baby thanks, in this way I find the product but how I can display all the products from frontend without product url?

Comment: @Federica did you created any categories in backend ?  you need to create `menu` and link the menu to that category-url....

Comment: @Baby yes, I created one category with a subcategory and I linked my product to them..

Comment: now check with `site-url/category-url/sub-category-url.html` @Federica , as you keep on assign products to those categories, you can display all those products in single link....

Comment: @Baby this url produces 'PAGE NOT FOUND' but the categories tree is correct (new category I've created is default category daughter).. In my home I've not some menu item for products and categories

Comment: @Federica can you check `site-url/category-url.html`  is working or not ?

Comment: @Baby this url is correct and it show me subcategory but any products..

Comment: please make sure you assigned those products to particular  category & sub-category @Federica

Comment: yes of course! I linked my product to both categories..

Comment: @Federica try reindexing once, `system > index Management`

Comment: @Baby thanks, I resolved my problem adding some phtml code into homepage content from CMS>Pages

Comment: @Federica glad to hear that, if you want you can post answer and accept it.....

Comment: Yes, of course! I added into homepage content the following code:                   {{block type="catalog/product_list" 
name="home.catalog.product.list" 
alias="products_homepage" 
category_id="2" 
template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}                                                                             and then I refreshed the cache (from System>Cache Management)

Comment: @Federica thats great, as the question should not come under `unanswered list ` we need to post an answer, thats okay :-) let me post an answer.....

Comment: @Federica can you check this link once : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If the product is present in `backend` than it should display in frontend , if you did't created any `category & menu`, than it may not display once you visit the site or search in site .try checking with **site-url/product-url.html** .

**credits : @Federica**

to display in home page , add following code to home page content & Refresh cache

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```